# Is it possible to use two HM-10 on two Arduinos for bidirectional Bluetooth communication?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am thinking about using the HM-10, or some other bluetooth module on two Arduino boards for Bluetooth communication.

What I want is to be able to send and recieve data from a single Arduino board. For example, if D2 is HIGH on Arduino A, HM-10A will transmit a signal to HM-10 B, telling Arduino B a button is pressed. And if a D2 on Arduino B is HIGH, HM-10B will transmit data to HM-10A, telling Arduino A a button is pressed.

If it is not possible with the HM-10, are there any other development boards that are capable of this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

1. Take care to avoid data collision
2. Make it half duplex to ensure you will miss any data or receive garbage data.

Example 1 [here](https://www.mrswirlyeyes.com/tutorials/bluetooth_hm_10) , first result in search result.